# What is the motivation behind the study of pattern-avoiding permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, applications, motivation

There is a ton of research on pattern-avoiding permutations (permutations that do not contain some designated [permutation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern)).  We're figuring out how to enumerate them, what random ones are like, algorithms to generate them, etc.

What is the importance of studying pattern-avoiding permutations?  Is there mathematical significance beyond simply being interesting in their own right?  What are the applications?

Comment: For example the study of the Tamari poset can be done by 132-avoiding permutations. And the Tamari poset is used in physics and algebra. See www.math.tamu.edu/~maguiar/Loday.pdf